# How can Map be given access to the keys of a Dataset?

Tags: map, dataset, associations

Consider an example `Dataset`:

```
icds = Dataset[
  Map[
   Association[
     Thread[Rule[{"brand", "flavor", "parameter", "response"}, #]]] &,
   {
    {"a", "vanilla", 1, RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 10]},
    {"b", "vanilla", 1.5, RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 10]},
    {"a", "chocolate", 2, RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 10]},
    {"b", "chocolate", 2.5, RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], 10]}
    }
   ]
  ]
```

Now I'm examining `"response"`, grouped according to some function applied to `"parameter"`. Here I'm using `Floor` but in general the function is expensive enough that I can't calculate it more than once.

```
rds = icds[GroupBy[Floor[#"parameter"] &], All, "response"]
```

[image]

So far, so good. The expensive result of `Floor` is stored in the `Key`s.

Now I'd like to do an operation where the `Key` is used for something. For instance, I'll make a pair of plots where the key is used as the `PlotLabel`. But any further `Query` or `Map` applied to the dataset seems to apply only to the values and not the keys. I can achieve the right result by exiting `Dataset` land with a double application of `Normal`.

```
Row@Map[
 SmoothHistogram[#[[2]], PlotLabel -> #[[1]]] &,
 Normal[Normal[rds]]
]
```

[image]

That is the desired outcome, but `Normal[Normal[]]` seems like a workaround. How can the `Key`s of the `Dataset` be made available to `Map` (or similar) without transforming to `Normal` form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Histograms can be generated within the dataset using `AssociationMap`:

```
icds[
  GroupBy[Floor[#"parameter"] &] /*
  AssociationMap[#[[1]] -> SmoothHistogram[#[[2]], PlotLabel -> #[[1]]] &]
, All
, "response"
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

If desired, the histograms can be extracted from the dataset by adding an additional ascending operator to convert the association's values into a `Row`:

```
icds[
  GroupBy[Floor[#"parameter"] &] /*
  AssociationMap[#[[1]] -> SmoothHistogram[#[[2]], PlotLabel -> #[[1]]] &] /*
  (Row @ Values @ # &)
, All
, "response"
]
```

[image: row screenshot]

---

**Side Note**

One might be tempted to express the row conversion as `Values /* Row`.  This does not work because `Values` is a descending operator.  When descending operators are composed *after* ascending operators (`AssociationMap` in this case), the query plan can give surprising results.  Here is the plan generated when the conversion is an ascending operator:

```
Dataset`ShowPlan[
  GroupBy[Floor[#"parameter"] &] /*
  AssociationMap[#[[1]] -> SmoothHistogram[#[[2]], PlotLabel -> #[[1]]] &] /*
  (Row @ Values @ # &)
, All
, "response"
]

(*
  GroupBy[Floor[#parameter]&] /*
  Map[Map[GeneralUtilities`Slice[response]]] /*
  AssociationMap[#1[[1]]->SmoothHistogram[#1[[2]],PlotLabel->#1[[1]]]&] /*
  (Row[Values[#1]]&)
*)
```

Now observe how the plan is altered when the row conversion composition contains the descending operator `Values`:

```
Dataset`ShowPlan[
  GroupBy[Floor[#"parameter"] &] /*
  AssociationMap[#[[1]] -> SmoothHistogram[#[[2]], PlotLabel -> #[[1]]] &] /*
  Values /*
  Row
, All
, "response"
]

(*
  Map[Map[GeneralUtilities`Slice[response]]] /*
  GroupBy[Floor[#parameter]&] /*
  AssociationMap[#1[[1]]->SmoothHistogram[#1[[2]],PlotLabel->#1[[1]]]&] /*
  Values /*
  Row
*)
```

The latter plan does not generate the desired results (in fact, it generates an error).  The v10.0.1 documentation is silent on the meaning of trailing descending operators in a composition, so perhaps it is best to avoid them for the time being.